# How big should a file be before I don't inline it in html?

Tags: javascript, css, html, web-optimization

Google recommends optimising web pages by inlining small CSS & javascript.

Ref: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service/InlineSmallResources

But at what point should we stop inlining, is there a recommended maximum number of characters that a file should be before it is better to reference instead of inline the file?

Comment: If you have only few elements on the page and only few classes/ids for that elements I think that you could maybe benefit from inline styling otherwise it's bad practice. I mean if you calling css document for other 100+ elements than it's useless to have inline styling for couple of them.

Comment: I think the point of the article is not define a "minumum" size for a file to be not inline. It's more of a heads up to use as less request  as possible (Reduce round trip time). Don't decide if you want to use inline-scripting or styling by performance indicators. You should try to minify and merge related css and js files into one.

Comment: And of course what @NicoO said, always merge css documents when possible.

Comment: The whole point of doing this is to minimize HTTP requests.  If you are building a single page site, that has very minimal content for whatever reason, then yeah, you might as well use inline styling, it removes the need of the HTTP request to another file and thus saves you a few milliseconds. Just understand that if you would otherwise have just one HTTP request out to a single CSS File.  And you remove that request by placing the code inline, you are only saving yourself a few dozen milliseconds at the cost of easy edits to the page.

Comment: because of pipelining, it's actually usually faster to download two 50kb css files from 2 <link> tags than to download a single 100kb file or to import the 2nd 50kb file from the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously this isn't a complete list, but I think this is a decent set of guidelines.

**Situations when inlining might be beneficial:**

- Styles or scripts are only used on that page
- Single page application
- Styles are determined to be "critical", and will make the page appear as if it is loading faster. See this article: http://css-tricks.com/authoring-critical-fold-css/

**Situations when inlining might be harmful:**

- Styles or scripts are used on multiple pages - if inlined on each page, they will not be cached and need to be downloaded again on each page

Comment: I was writing an answer, but you beat me and I think you summarized better.  I think the key thing this article is targeting is minimal websites, where there is a single page and very minimal amount of content.